# Custom UINavigationItem class - Title dependent on Active UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uinavigationitem

I've created an App which has three storyboards. ( & multiple VC's) I am creating a global NavigationItem class, that I can enter in storyboard so every view controller inherits the same information and I only have to code one page rather than copying and pasting into each VC.

I want to set the title programmatically. The title can change depending on which storyboard is active and what size phone is present. i.e full title or shorthand if it is displaying on an iPhone SE.

I can't use. UIStoryboard as a bool, as it doesn't conform. How can I tell which storyboard I'm in, so it can set the title in an if statement? The code i've written is wrong and doesn't work for the storyboard.

My code setup so far for my NavigationItemCustom class is bellow I am finding it difficult to find which storyboard i'm in? Can anyone push me in the right direction, please. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
class NavigationBarSetUp: UINavigationItem {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


        let currentstoryboard = UIStoryboard()
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "First", bundle: nil)
        //let storyboard2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)
        //let storyboard3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Third", bundle: nil)

        //Current title
        self.title = nil

        if currentstoryboard == storyboard1 && (screenWidth == 320) {

            self.title = " diet 1"
            print ("called short title")

        } else if currentstoryboard == storyboard1 && (screenWidth > 320) {

            // rest of screen sizes
            self.title = " Welcome to diet 1"
            print ("called full title")
        }

        // Repeat if statement for storyboards 2 & 3 with different titles.


        // Rest of Class code - Bar Button Item Setup
        self.hidesBackButton = false
        self.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

        // Left Side Button Setup

        let buttonView = UIToolbar()
            buttonView.frame = .init(x: 0, y:-7, width: 30, height: 30)

        // Setting UIToolbar Transparency of the toolbar 
            buttonView.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                        forToolbarPosition: .any,
                                        barMetrics: .default)
            buttonView.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)


        // This is a UIView the Toolbar will sit inside which will then be placed into the Navigationbar.
        let navigationContainer = UIView()
        navigationContainer.frame = .init(x: 0, y:0, width: 30, height: 30)

        // ButtonBarItems Set Up

        let ModalButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: self, action: #selector(NotesButtonClicked))

        let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        negativeSpace.width = -10

        //Add ButtonBarItems into the UIToolbar ButtonView
            buttonView.setItems([negativeSpace, ModalButton], animated: false)

        // Add UItoolbar into UIView
            navigationContainer.addSubview(buttonView)

        //Icon Size to fit
            buttonView.sizeToFit()

        //Convert UIView into Barbutton Item to set in the Navigation Bar
        let topLeft = UIBarButtonItem()
        topLeft.customView = navigationContainer

        self.setLeftBarButton(topLeft, animated: false)


        // Setup of the Right Handside Menu Button

        let BurgerButton = UIButton()
            BurgerButton.frame = .init(x: -1, y: 0.5, width: 62, height: 25)
            BurgerButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BurgerButton1.pdf"), for: .normal)


            BurgerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        let topRight = UIBarButtonItem()
        topRight.customView = BurgerButton

        self.setRightBarButton(topRight, animated: true)

    }

        // Calls the Left Button Action. 

        func NotesButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            print("Notes Modal Is Called")

            //Code here

    }

        // Calls the Right Button Action. 

        func MenuClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

            print("Menu is Opened - Rightside")

            //Code here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are doing a couple things that won't work:

```
    let currentstoryboard = UIStoryboard()
```

You just created a **NEW** instance of a (empty) `UIStoryBoard` object...

```
    let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "First", bundle: nil)
```

You just created a **NEW** instance of a `UIStoryBoard` object, referencing the Storyboard named "First" (assuming it exists in your app).

Those two instances could *never* be equal.

`UIViewController` has a `.storyboard` property, which is "The storyboard from which the view controller originated."

However, even if you tried:

```
    let currentstoryboard = self.storyboard
    let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "First", bundle: nil)
    if currentstoryboard == storyboard1 { ... }
```

They will *still* never be equal, because `storyboard1` is a *new* instance.

You *might* try:

```
    let sbName = self.storyboard?.value(forKey: "name") as? String
    if sbName == "First" { ... }
```

Unfortunately, ***that does not seem to be documented by Apple, and may very possibly and up getting your app rejected***.

I'd think you would be much better off using your own variables / properties to keep track of what's what.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes and explaining it that is very useful! 
I wouldn't want to do anything which could get the App rejected, If its no direct way of initializing this code from the class alone. Thinking out-loud perhaps I could add an observer with NSnotificationcentre into each initial VC of each storyboard in the view will appear. Then listen for this in the class and change the title accordingly. Or maybe i'll give up and just set the title in each view controller with an individual if statement for the title length where needed. Although this would be a bit repetitive!

Comment: Are you using the same VC classes in each Storyboard?

Comment: I'm using a few different classes in each storyboard for VC. But you gave me an idea surely I could just make three different UINavigationItem classes each with a corresponding title change and simply assign one to each navigation bar in each storyboard. That would be a lot quicker than repeating code across VC. It's not as elegant as using one class but a lot quicker with less code.

Comment: Should I mark your answer correct? I think it would be helpful for people looking in the future to know that trying to find an active storyboard could potentially mean having your App rejected?

Comment: I'm sure it wouldn't hurt... I'd say there is enough in our comments for clarity.